# Click action for button which is loaded from a html page to a webview in Android

Tags: android, html, webview

```
webView=(WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/hello.html");
```

I got the button displayed but I don't know to give click action for that button.Please help me with some code.

Comment: show how the `hello.html` looks like

Answer (score 0):

In html, for the tag `<input>` `onclick` attribute is used to perform some action when we click on that particular buttton. And the action would be written in JavaScript language.

```
<html>
<script type = "text/javascript">
 function myfunction(){ 
    // your action 
}
</script>
<body>
<input type = "button" value = "Click" onClick = "myfunction()">
</body></html>
```

Go through some online tutorial like [W3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Comment: that's fine ,but that is not working when I call that button(which is from a html page)to a webview in android